# Mathematical issue regarding a variant of Quantum Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator

Suppose I have a potential of the form $$V(x) =  \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}kx^2 &\text{ if }x>0 \\ {\infty} &\text{ if }x<0 \end{cases} $$

We know for the usual HO one introduces $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ and gets nice algebraic relations between them and eventually deduces the energy levels to be $E_n = \hbar w(n+\frac{1}{2})$ purely algebraically mainly through various commutation relations.

Now suppose I do the following: Instead of working with $V(x)$ I retain my old HO potential $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ but restrict my Hilbert space to the set of functions vanishing for $x<0$. So denote $D$ the original Hilbert space for the regular QHO (in general it will not be all of $L^2(-\infty,\infty)$ because $p$ and $x$ and their polynomials are densely defined) and let $A$ be the set of functions in $L^2(-\infty,\infty)$ which vanish for $x<0$ and let: $$D'= D  \cap A $$

My question is: Instead of working with the the Hamiltonian $H= \frac{1}{2m}P^2 + V(x)$ defined on $D$ couldn't we work with $H' = \frac{1}{2m}P^2 + \frac{1}{2}kx^2$ defined on $D'$? If indeed this is the case then to get the energy levels for $H$ (defined on $D$) we can instead use $H'$ (defined on $D'$) and use the same commutation relations and algebra as for the regular QHO (the only difference is that operators are acting on $D'$ instead of $D$ but the commutation relations are still the same). This should mean that this system would have the same energy levels as the regular QHO but it does not (although it's close). So what am I missing?

Comment: What are the functions in $D$ that vanish for $x < 0$? That is, what are the QHO eigenstates that don't penetrate on that side of the potential?

Comment: There are non. All eigenfunctions are nonzero on both sides of the real line.

Comment: So $D^{\prime}$ contains what?

Comment: [Linkedf](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/508962/what-are-the-energy-eigenstates-for-a-modified-quantum-harmonic-oscillator). Look at odd solutions.

Comment: @Dan It's as I defined it above: the restriction of QHO Hilbert space to functions that vanish for $x<0$. The eigenfunctions of this new hamiltonian on $D'$ will surely be different from the original QHO but it seems that the eigenvalues (i.e. energy levels) should not be different since with this new hamiltonian you can do the same kind of ladder operator things as in the original QHO hamiltonian. But it turns out they're not, hence my query.

Comment: [Helpful link](https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/physics/quvis/simulations_html5/sims/half-harmonic-oscillator/half-harmonic-oscillator.html).

Comment: I see how the odd solutions (restricted to be zero on the other side) are the new eigenfunctions but what I'm trying to ask is something different: how can we reconcile the fact that only odd energy levels are allowed with the fact that with my new hamiltonian (equivalent to the old hamiltonian) you can do the same kind of ladder operator shenanigans which ultimately lead to integer spaced energy levels (as opposed to just odd).

Comment: There are hermiticity subtleties at the origin, so tread carefully with your expectations about creation and annihilation operators.